# Downloading Generated XML File

Tags: plugin-development, widgets

I'm making a Widget which presents users with categories as drop down list. When user selects category and press download, I want to get all posts under category and download them. I have faced a problem on downloading. 
I do something like

```
$xml = ''; //generated XML with Simple XML
header('Content-type: text/xml');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="text.xml"');
echo $xml->asXML();
```

I get headers already sent. So I added buffering to init with code:

```
add_action('init', 'do_output_buffer');

function do_output_buffer() {
        ob_start();
}
```

and in my `MY_Widget::widget()` I add the code `echo ob_get_clean();` after `echo $xml->asXML();` explained above. Here it works except it exports whole page (with my XML) as single XML file.

Is there a way to download file without including whole page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to clean buffer and then do my stuffs and call exit

```
ob_clean(); //clear buffer
    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="text.xml"');
    echo $xml->asXML(); 
exit();
```